# How to copy and append a string to the end of a line

Tags: linux

I have a file containing lines like the following:

```
a b c patch/sample/upgrade.sql
a b c demo/sample/script.sh
```

I want to be able to copy everything starting from the position after "c" to the last "/" and append it to the end of each line in the file. For example:

```
a b c patch/sample/upgrade.sql patch/sample
a b c demo/sample/script.sh demo/sample
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

if every line starts with `a b c`, that should do:

```
$> sed 's@a b c \(.*\)/[^/]*@& \1@g' foo.txt 
a b c patch/sample/upgrade.sql patch/sample
a b c demo/sample/script.sh demo/sample
```

Otherwise, just adapt the first part.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `awk` then you can try:

```
awk '
{
    last=x
    n=split($4,tmp,/[/]/)
    for(i=1;i<n;i++) {
        last=last sep tmp[i]; 
        sep="/"
    }
    $0=$0 FS last
}1' file
```

```
$ cat file
a b c patch/sample/upgrade.sql
a b c demo/sample/script.sh
```

```
$ awk '
{
    last=x
    n=split($4,tmp,/[/]/)
    for(i=1;i<n;i++) {
        last=last sep tmp[i]; 
        sep="/"
    }
    $0=$0 FS last
}1' file
a b c patch/sample/upgrade.sql patch/sample
a b c demo/sample/script.sh /demo/sample
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from @fredtantini's answer, try the following in a terminal

```
sed -r 's|(\w+ \w+ \w+ /((.*)?/)*(.*))|\1 \3|' foo.txt
```

If you want to output this to a file,

```
sed -r 's|(\w+ \w+ \w+ /((.*)?/)*(.*))|\1 \3|' foo.txt > newFoo.txt
```